# React: I have a try/catch block in a service that I'm trying to add an Axios call to but I'm not sure where to put it

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, try-catch, axios

I have a try/catch block inside a React service that I now need to add the actual Axios call and make a GET request to an external API in order to get live data back and then set that data response to an existing variable, but I'm not sure how to do it. I have my service listed below, any feedback or insight on how to better accomplish this would be a huge help

customerService.js

```
import { logError } from './logging'

export async function getCustomer(customer = {}) {
  try {
    const { customerId } = customer
    console.info('Customer ID:', customerId)

    // TODO: Make call to new API
    return new Promise(res => {
      setTimeout(() => res({}), 1000)
    })
  } catch (error) {
    logError(error)
    throw error
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `getCustomer()` function is `async`, you should be able to `await` your Axios call:

```
import Axios from 'axios'
import { logError } from './logging'

export async function getCustomer(customer = {}) {
  try {
    const { customerId } = customer
    console.info('Customer ID:', customerId)

    const result = await Axios.get("http://example.com");

    return new Promise(res => {
      // I assume this is where you want to use the API result?
      setTimeout(() => res(result), 1000)
    })
  } catch (error) {
    logError(error)
    throw error
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm hitting the endpoint and getting a response as I can see via the network tab under my developer tools, but when I try to map out the response I can't drill deeper than the top level of each object. For instance the object returns as a single object with 3 nested objects inside(account, contact, site). I push the data response into my ```customer``` object and then attempt to iterate over it using dot notation like ```customer.contact.name``` but the result comes back as undefined. If I stop at ```customer.contact``` my app renders but doesn't show data and I'm completely scratching my head

Comment: How are you pushing the response into `customer`? Set a breakpoint in your browser's dev tools and look at what's happening. Alternatively, `console.log(customer)` and/or `console.log(result)` will be your friends here.

Comment: I actually used the Redux dev tools to figure it out! It was returning the response inside ```data``` so I just changed the axios call to ```const { data } ``` and was able to work from there. Thanks so much for the help!